# Applying for post-doctoral fellowships whilst writing PhD thesis

Tags: phd, united-kingdom

Is it acceptable to apply for post-doctoral fellowships in the UK whilst writing my PhD thesis?

Comment: Location? Rules and customs vary from place to place.

Comment: How long will it take until you have handed in the thesis? If it takes another year, that's too early for most places, but one or two months might be OK.

Comment: @nick012000 , UK

Comment: @lighthousekeeper it should be less than a year

Comment: Some post-doc fellowships need to be applied to 1year before defending... it is really dependant of each one.

Comment: @Zenon I see, is there any website for the postdoc position inside the UK ?

Comment: I added UK to the question. I also removed _please note that I got my funding_, since it didn't seem relevant. Perhaps the OP can edit to clarify if it is important

Comment: Also an important tangential point, talk to your advisor(s) about that and general future plans. You'll have to talk to them about letters of recommendation anyway and they will know the customs in your field/country and what you are capable of. Thus they can likely tell you where to best apply. They might even know some open positions and other opportunities which aren't publicly advertised yet.

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to start applying for post-doctoral fellowship but I am still writing my thesis, is that acceptable?

Yes, assuming you can plausibly start on time. Starting a bit late is also largely acceptable.